# How could i do that? Illustrator? Photoshop?... or both?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-effects, patterns, illustrator-effects

The other day I found these illustrations of one of my favorite artists (Yone Kazuki) and I noticed the circles that were behind. As a kind of Sun and I would love to know how to do that kind of pattern (If it is a pattern...)
In what program would i do it? Photoshop or illustrator? And in case it could be done using some technique, what would be the process?

I imagine that they also have some texture ... the lines seem degraded, as if they were on a canvas. Could someone help me with this doubt?

Thank you very much in advance! ><

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is really too broad. There's a lot going on in those designs, far too much to describe all the processes involved. So, this is for just one part of the top image. I think Illustrator is best for this.

Draw a single line, then add a rotational transform in the Appearance panel to make a circle of thin lines.

Draw an irregular outer zig-zag line around the circle, and also a simple circle inside, combine both shapes using Pathfinder Minus Front, and use this as as a clipping mask on the circle of thin lines.

[image]

With the Pencil tool, draw a 1pt black random squiggly line over the whole thing, cut it, select the shape, and apply an opacity mask and paste the squiggly line you made as the opacity mask.

[image]

The final result.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for solving the question !!
I did not think that someone could answered me so fast .. and with guide photos! Thank you very much again! TTATT

Forgive me for being very nuisance, could I ask you one last thing?
Since it is an extensive topic as you good have explained to me, where could I find the information or the appropriate tutorials to learn how to make those suns?


Thank you very much (again) for having taken the trouble. Have a very nice day!! ><

Comment: @Kingcrownlight You could google for something like "radial patterns Illustrator tutorial". That would find lots of similar tutorials, but there are many different ways to make these kind of designs.